# Change MSCRM 2011 subgrid entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, subgrid

I know how to modify the FetchXml of the subgrid. I'm attempting to dynamically change a subgrid based on selections from optionsets with JS. Based on the optionsets, the subgrid will need to be able to display different entities (not at the same time).
Example: The subgrid is currently showing Accounts with a specific relationship type.  An optionset changes and now the subgrid should show Leads whose first name is John.

The error I'm receiving is "Entity Name specified in FetchXml does not match the entity name in the EntityExpression"

I feed the below fetch into the grid. It's just a multi-value search. rc_entitylist contains all entities in the system. rc_attributelist contains all the fields for the selected entity. The user selects an entity, selects a field to search, enters search criteria (one value per line) and then it populates the subgrid accordingly.

```
function runSearch() {
var entityname = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("rc_entitylist").getText();
var sgrid = "searchResults";
var fetchXml = '<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">'+
'<entity name="' + entityname + '">'+
'<all-attributes />' +
'<filter type="and">'+
'<filter type="or">';

    var textBoxLines = document.getElementById("rc_searchcriteria").innerText;
    var attributename = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("rc_attributelist").getText();
    var lines = textBoxLines.split(/\n/);
    for(var i=0;i < lines.length; i++){
    fetchXml = fetchXml + '<condition attribute="' + attributename + '" operator="eq" value="'+ lines[i] +'" />';
    }

  fetchXml = fetchXml + '</filter>'+
'</filter>'+
'</entity>'+
'</fetch>';
 updateXml(sgrid, fetchXml, entityname);
 }

 function updateXml(grid, xmlfield, entityname) {   
try {      
    var g = document.getElementById(grid).control;
    g.setParameter("fetchXml", xmlfield);
} catch (e) { }   
// Refresh the grid      
document.getElementById(grid).control.refresh();   
}
```

Comment: if you add some code will be more easy to understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about adding multiple subgrids to the form, and hiding/showing them based on the on-change event of the optionset?